# How to structure terrain generator in unity?

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine

I am learning C# with Unity and I am trying to create terrain generator. I made a class called `Terrain` which contains an array of class called `Chunk`. Chunk should be an array of square GameObjects.

The code looks like this:

```
public class Terrain : MonoBehaviour {

    public Chunk[] terrain;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        terrain[0] = new Chunk(0, 0);
    }
}
```

and class `Chunk` looks like this:

```
public class Chunk : MonoBehaviour {

    public int size;
    public GameObject tile;

    private GameObject[] chunk;
    private int xCoord, yCoord;

    public void Create(int chunkX, int chunkY){
        for(int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
                int xCoord = x + chunkX*size;
                int yCoord = y + chunkY*size;

                chunk[x + y*size] = GameObject.Instantiate(tile, new Vector3(xCoord, yCoord), Quaternion.identity);
                x = chunkX;
                y = chunkY;
            }
        }
    }

    //Constructor
    public Chunk(int chunkX, int chunkY) {
        xCoord = chunkX;
        yCoord = chunkY;
    }
}
```

I get 1 error and 1 warning:

```
You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword.  This is not allowed.  MonoBehaviours can only be added using AddComponent().


IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
```

How can I fix this and can you explain in newbie's terms why I can't use `new` for creating a new chunk. Also, why is array index out of range? Last question, is this structuring any good and how would you improve it or implement it differently?

Comment: Why does `Chunk` have to be a MonoBehavior? Usually the behaviors are attached to game objects, which is why you can't directly create them. The other error is easy, you aren't initializing the array, so `[0]` doesn't exist in the start method.

Comment: To be honest, I still don't understand what that ": MonoBehavior" means even tho I read about it. Could you explain it in a few sentences please?

Comment: It turns your class into something that can be attached to a game object, which then includes methods like `Start` and `Update` that are run so you can update properties of that game object. If you don't have to attach it to a game object, don't derive from `MonoBehavior`. You really should read through the [User Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/index.html) before trying scripting without knowing how things work.

Comment: Thanks Ron! I will read the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove `: MonoBehaviour` from your `Chunk` class as you do not any behaviour for that. This is just a holder class for your data, and it does not follow (does not need to either) start-update routine that MonoBehaviour extending classes do.